# Protected destructor of std::codecvt

Tags: c++, c++20

I have two questions about this new utility. I'm using g++10.3 with c++20.

1. Is there any reason that std::codecvt destructor is protected ?
2. Should we write a wrapper with a public destructor to use std::codecvt functional everytime?

Comment: I think the reason given at [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/%7Ecodecvt) is good enough: *"...the last object that implements this facet..."*

Comment: `std::codecvt` is meant to be derived from. The base class doesn't actually perform any conversion, so useless on its own. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "new utility"; `std::codeconv` already existed in C++98. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, trying to understand operations on encodings. Initially wanted to convert u8"some string" into byte array (std::vector<char> or std::string). This compiles for c++11 but since c++20 it doesn't. std::string s = u8"some string".

Comment: Well, C++20 wants one to use `char8_t` array or `std::u8string` for UTF-8 strings.  There is no specialization for `codecvt<char, char8_t>` provided with the library - if for some reason you want that, you'd have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Anyway, it can be done in the following way: std::string s = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(+u8"some string");
I only want to understand the structure of this classes. How they interact. And how to properly use these std::codecvt.